# Solr indexing HTML entities

Tags: indexing, solr, html-entities

I am indexing documents by Solr, which were scraped from the web. The documents contain HTML entities (such as `&pound;` or `&#163;`). Mostly the documents contain central european characters. Is there any charfilter for this task? I know solr.MappingCharFilterFactory, but using this would mean, that I have to define the mappings myself. I would be happier with a shared solution maintained by a community. Thanks for your help!

Comment: fifigyuri, you asked "Is there any charfilter for this task?" Let me get this straight: Do you want to convert accented chars to non-accented before indexing a document (that is like convert "állat" to "allat")? And you do not want to assemble and maintain a txt file of the char mapping?

Comment: @bpgergo, I have tackled the áóüőťďľšč... characters, for these MappingCharFilter is fine. I would like to have mappings for the HTMLentities. It means that &#252; or &uuml; would be translated to ü. But probably, the simplest for that would be just to extend my mappings. Wanted to know whether, there aren't these cases already tackled for web specific texts/characters in Solr. If you know any such a solution, ready made, please share. Thanks!

Comment: I see. Unfortunately i don't know such ready made mapping.

Answer (score 1):

There is `solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory`, which converts `HTML` entities, but it also strips `HTML` tags.